# Reading/Writnig BSON file

Tags: c++, bson, nlohmann-json

I am using the https://github.com/nlohmann/json libary for writing out my object to BSON. I have validated creating the `json` instance by writing the file out to json for review, so that portion of the code is working as expected. I am having issues with it once I swap back to bson though.

Here is the snippet of code I am working with:

```
//I have written out json_triangle_container to verify it looks correct
//so I am sure the problem is not here
json json_instance = <my function to create this instance>
std::vector<std::uint8_t> v_bson = json::to_bson(json_instance);

//writing the vector out here
auto bsonFilename = std::string("json_instance.bson");
std::ofstream bsonfile(bsonFilename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
bsonfile.write((char*)&v_bson[0], v_bson.size() * sizeof(v_bson[0]));
bsonfile.close();

//reading it back in here
std::ifstream r_file(bsonFilename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
std::streampos size = r_file.tellg();
r_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
char* memblock = new char[size];
r_file.read(memblock, size);
r_file.close();

//printing out the json object for testing
auto json_instance_read = json::from_bson(memblock); //this is where it is blowing up
std::cout << json_instance_read << std::endl;
```

I get an exception that says:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF4EE6A839 in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: nlohmann::detail::parse_error at memory location 0x0000006AB4D5F470.
```

It is also worth noting if I call `json::from_bson(v_bson )` it parses fine. I validated the array size being read in is the same size as the vector I wrote out. So this is leading me to believe I did something wrong in how I wrote the `bson` out initially.

---

**Edit**
Using some online tools to convert the bson file I generated to json it seems the writing is correct. So that points to my read function being the issue.

Doing some more debugging, it looks like in the `v_bson` `vector` the 3 item has the value `'\0'` which I think is throwing off the reader and it is stopping short before reading the entire file. I confirmed this by checking the size of the `memblock` and it is only 3 characters long.

So the question changes a bit:
**How do I tell `ifstream` reader to ignore what it seem to think is an EOF character?**

Everything I have found says to make sure to initialize it with `std::ios::binary`, which I do:

```
std::ifstream r_file(bsonFilename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
```

Comment: **Don't** access the `std::vector` contents using `(char *)v_bson[0]`. Use `v_bson.data()` to get the address of the underlying data; a `reinterpret_cast` may be required.

Comment: @BobDalgleish So I just swapped that out and I have the same result as before.